# TCP Connect to Azure Fails

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, azure

I recently deployed an Azure app to the staging environment which is supposed to accept TCP packets in port 2993. When run in the Azure emulator, it does this very well, and performs exactly as it should.

However, now that it is on Azure's staging servers, whenever I try to connect to the TCP port, i get the following SocketException:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

My web app has two instances, one is a worker role (it has 2993 configured in its endpoints) and a web role (only for port 80). Port 80, by the way, functions perfectly. The web app was created with Visual Studio in C#. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you confident about the ordering in your last two paragraphs? If you used an IP address I wouldn't expect there to be _any_ hostname resolution -- unless you actually tried to do nameservice lookups on an IP address?

Comment: Just a few questions/clarifications: The worker role port is on an Input Endpoint? How do you then bind to the endpoint in code, and how do you know what port to bind to (did you force the private port or allow for dynamic assignment)? when accessing via the staging slot, are you using the <guid>.cloudapp.net name?

Comment: i do not mention the endpoint in code. I do use the <guid>.cloudapp.net name.

Comment: @sarnold: good point. See, my C# client uses the line Dns.GetHostEntry("e7cb7daa205b4bfdaf1ee58f0cf5e635.cloudapp.net"); when i said i was using the IP address, I was mistakenly telling the compiler it was a domain name. I have taken that paragraph out of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to explain what was the issue and why adding above code solve this problem for others benefit.

In your worker role, you configure any TCP endpoint along with any port number. When this VM starts the VM is provisioned to use this port and firewall is included an exception to provide access to this port. By the time your is ready to start your Azure VM already have TCP/IP address and configured port is enabled.

Now when your role starts and if you have any service or application required access this port you really need to l

For example If I have Tomcat/Java configured in my worker role, I must have to create a TCP listener on my configured port. This can be done when my worker role starts as below:

1. Get the IP address and Port number of the current role instance
2. Create a TCP Listener and start on this IP address and Port
3. Add the code to perform step 1) and 2) in my worker role OnStart() function.

The code will look like as below:

```
TcpListener TomcatPortListener = new  TcpListener(RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["TomcatWeb80"].IPEndpoint);
TomcatPortListener.Start();
```

In your case you you did exactly the same you got the IP address and Port number from and then created an endpoint from a socket address using IP/Port:

```
RoleInstanceEndpoint externalEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["TCPin"];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint.Address, externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint.Port);
localEndPoint.Create();
```

It is a must setting for any web or worker role which create TCP endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem had something to do with the program's detection of the server's IP address. By using the following server code instead, I managed to fix the problem:

```
RoleInstanceEndpoint externalEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["TCPin"];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint.Address, externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint.Port);
```

The IPEndpoint can then be used with the tcpListener socket.